# Loading project-specific log information into log files

Tags: log4j, slf4j

I am using Eclipse and I am creating a web project. I am also using SLF4J for storing logs in a log file.

I am putting the `log4j.properties` file into the `WEB-INF/classes` folder .

When I access the login page, all of the associated logs and my debug statement log are being loaded into the log file, but I want a specific log (i.e., project specific log) to be loaded into the log file instead of other logs.

On the log file I can see:

```
10/20/2010 10:16:24 - DEBUG - org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.sax   
.   
10/20/2010 10:16:24 - DEBUG - org.apache.commons.digester.Digester - [ObjectCreateRule]{resource-config/resource}New org.ajax4jsf.javascript.AjaxScript   
.      
10/20/2010 10:16:24 - DEBUG - org.apache.commons.digester.Digester - [ObjectCreateRule]{resource-config/resource}New    
.    
10/20/2010 10:16:24 - DEBUG - org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.sax
.
10/20/2010 10:16:24 - DEBUG - org.apache.commons.digester.Digester - [ObjectCreateRule]{resource-config/resource}New org.ajax4jsf.javascript.AjaxScript
.
10/20/2010 10:16:24 - DEBUG - org.apache.commons.digester.Digester - [ObjectCreateRule]{resource-config/resource}New 
.
```

Can anyone help me to find out how to store specific project related logs into log file?

Answer (score 0):

Have something like the following in your log4j.properties file:

```
log4j.logger.com.foo.logingubbins=DEBUG, loginfilelogger

log4j.appender.app=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.loginfilelogger.File=c:/logs/login.log
log4j.appender.loginfilelogger.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.loginfilelogger.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p [%c (%F:%L)] %n \t %m %n
```

That first line tells the logger to use a new logger for com.foo.logingubbins, which you direct to a separate file.  You might want to add an `additivity` statement in there as well if you want it entirely separated.

The [log4j manual](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) can give you some useful examples, though I have to admit that the information on additivity is a little hazy.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Thanks for reply. I added the folowing steps into log4j.properties file
```

log4j.logger.org.apache.commons.digester=ERROR
log4j.category.se.bilprovningen.prippe=DEBUG,R

Now i am able to store project specific log into log file.

Thanks
Arvind